# Schengen visa requirements for traveling on a European Disney Cruise?

Tags: visas, schengen, cruising, disney

Do I need a single entry or a multiple entry Schengen if I am travelling on a Disney cruise that starts in Barcelona and then calls on ports in France then Italy?

Answer (score 2):

If the cruise does not call at any port outside the Schengen area, a single-entry visa should be enough as no border checks are required in this case (cf. annex VI of the [Schengen Borders code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02006R0562-20131126)).